# React: Keep expensive component mounted

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a Single-Page-App with React & React Router. One page contains a Google Maps component that is expensive to create (7$ per 1000 instances), so when users navigate back and forth, this generates cost.

My idea would be to create the Maps Component somewhere globally and somehow inject it into the `PageComponent` on mount, so that the same instance can be reused. Any ideas if and how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

In an old project I did something similar: during component unmount phase you can move the map's node (so vanilla JavaScript DOM API here… no React) inside another DOM note (hidden).

When your React app component is mounted you must check the presence of the DOM node, and in this case move it inside the React container instead of creating a new app.

Probably you'll need to trigger some map repaint event after that (maybe running a window `resize` event is enough).

Comment: Doesn't this conflict with React's Virtual DOM? I guess I could add a DOM Node somewhere using the JavaScript API, but I don't see a way to give back control to React? 

Comment: Not until you _don't_ touch nodes that React expect to be there. You can't modify nodes created by React (you'll get errors if you do this), but it doesn't care about nodes generated by 3rd party JavaScript, even if inside the React DOM tree.

Comment: @hendra ah! Now I see something I missed from your question. This works if your map implementation *is not* react-based… or at least it uses another `ReactDOM.render` call (so a totally different React application, where you can't share stuff)

Comment: Yes, at the moment I'm using @react-google-maps/api, but I might consider using vanilla js for the map & markers. Thanks!